# How to reference models in junction model with Sequelize 6 (and 7?) cli generated models

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a very simple structure for managing permissions where I have a table of users and a table of roles and a many-to-many mapping between them. This is working in the "old" way of setting up Sequelize. But, I'm about to add a bunch more complicated stuff, and am moving to the cli/migration model of defining models. I figured I'd start by getting my existing stuff working the new way.

As I understand things, there's no way to pass association information to the CLI during the generate phase, so you have to manually go back and add the associations. Moreover, when using this method instead of `sync`, you also have to create a separate migration file for the junction table. This can be facilitated by the generate command, but again needs to be manually configured.

I have all of that "done", such that `db:migrate` works; however, I'm running into errors when I try to actually use it in Node.

Here are the (modified) files in `./models`:

**role.js**:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Role extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: models.UserRole
      })
    }
  }
  Role.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Role',
  });
  return Role;
};
```

**user.js**:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: models.UserRole
      })
    }
  }
  User.init({
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

**userrole.js**:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class UserRole extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  UserRole.init({
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: User, // <--- this is the complaint
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    roleId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: Role,
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'UserRole',
  });
  return UserRole;
};
```

These are all read in with the autogenerated `index.js`.

When I spin things up with `nodemon`, it complains

```
userrole.js:20
        model: User,
               ^

ReferenceError: User is not defined
```

I tried modifying that line to `model: models.User`, but then it complains `ReferenceError: models is not defined`.

I'm sure I'm missing something quite simple here, but, how do I get those references into the model file for the junction table?

FWIW, this is with

```
sequelize@6.16.0
node v14.17.3
```

and I have it using sqlite as the dialect in the development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to remove `references` option and define all links in `associate`:

```js
static associate(models) {
       UserRole.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
       UserRole.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'roleId' });
    }
```